# (fields.E331) Field specifies a many-to-many relation through model 'models_groups', which has not been installed

Tags: django

> ERRORS: login.Freelancer.groups: (fields.E331) Field specifies a
>   many-to-many relation through model 'login.Freelancer_groups', which
>   has not been installed. login.Freelancer.user_permissions:
>   (fields.E331) Field specifies a many-to-many relation through model
>   'login.Freelancer_user_permissions', which has not been installed.
>   message_board.Post.author: (fields.E301) Field defines a relation with
>   the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out.
>           HINT: Update the relation to point at 'settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL'.

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.tests.custom_user import CustomUserManager
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.http import urlquote
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin
from crm import settings


class FreelancerManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, name, skills, password=None):
        if not name:
            raise ValueError('Users must have a unique name ')

        user = self.model(
            name=self.name,
            skills=skills,
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, name, skills, password):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            name,
            password=password,
            skills=skills,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class Freelancer(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='name',
                            max_length=20,
                            unique=True, )

    field_of_interest = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    skills = models.TextField()
    experience = models.TextField()

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = FreelancerManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'name'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['skills']

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'auth_user'
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/users/%s/" % urlquote(self.name)

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.name

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.name

    def __str__(self):  # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        # "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, applabel):
        # "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        # "Is the user a member of staff?"
        # "Simplest possible answer: All admins are staf"
        return self.is_admin
```

**admin.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import ReadOnlyPasswordHashField
from .models import Freelancer


class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for creating new users. Includes all the required
    fields, plus a repeated password."""
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = Freelancer
        fields = ('name', 'skills')

    def clean_password2(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user


class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for updating users. Includes all the fields on
    the user, but replaces the password field with admin's
    password hash display field.
    """
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()

    class Meta:
        model = Freelancer
        fields = ('name', 'password', 'skills','is_admin')

    def clean_password(self):
        # Regardless of what the user provides, return the initial value.
        # This is done here, rather than on the field, because the
        # field does not have access to the initial value
        return self.initial["password"]


class FreelancerAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    # The forms to add and change user instances
    form = UserChangeForm
    add_form = UserCreationForm

    # The fields to be used in displaying the User model.
    # These override the definitions on the base UserAdmin
    # that reference specific fields on auth.User.
    list_display = ('name', 'skills', 'is_admin')
    list_filter = ('is_admin',)
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('name', 'password')}),
        ('Personal info', {'fields': ('skills',)}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_admin',)}),
    )
    # add_fieldsets is not a standard ModelAdmin attribute. UserAdmin
    # overrides get_fieldsets to use this attribute when creating a user.
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('name', 'skills', 'password1', 'password2')}
         ),
    )
    search_fields = ('name',)
    ordering = ('name',)
    filter_horizontal = ()


# Now register the new UserAdmin...
admin.site.register(Freelancer, FreelancerAdmin)
admin.site.unregister(Group)
```

**settings.py**

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/checklist/
# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '&_j_tz#06jbpo5shiy62x$qxa*t68_n@q4@$pee4(a()5vyt#9'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True


ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'auth.User'
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'login.Freelancer'
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'login',
    'message_board'
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'crm.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'crm.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

> *And i have one more named app message_board which models.py is here*

**models.py of message_board App**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
            default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(
            blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: Have you defined `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'your_app_name.Freelancer'` in `settings.py` ?

Comment: yes sir , I have defined see this is I have defined
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'auth.User'
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'login.Freelancer'
where login my app name and the first one is for previous user auth .

Comment: Do you really have two **AUTH_USER_MODEL**. or you are showing an example. Because there can be only one **AUTH_USER_MODEL** ! If they are two , comment the _previous_ one i.e. `# AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'auth.User' ` and use your custom one(`login.Freelancer`).

Comment: yes Kapil sir, Still I'm getting same errors as above. Nothing has changed.

Comment: I think then `PermissionsMixin` [which depends on `django.contrib.auth`, `django.contrib.contenttypes`] is causing troubles. Can you show your settings.py, there something is not right there. Are you using both ?

Comment: ohhk here it is
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
SECRET_KEY = 'mkjel_*7$up*t2e2jd7njw)#zz8m%&e%s-5=*ac4*j_b63jlej'
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
h.User'
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'login.Freelancer'
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'login',
    'message_board'
]

Comment: MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
ROOT_URLCONF = 'crm.urls'

Comment: its too large I hav to make tow more comment btw when I remove permissionmixin then some errors get removed and the error is--

message_board.Post.author: (fields.E301) Field defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out.
        HINT: Update the relation to point at 'settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL'.

I cannot just write all code here If u give me email Id so I'll mail you 
And thankyou for being such a nice guy

Comment: You should edit your Question with the settings.py contents. Don't show it in the comments. Also `message_board.Post.author(ForeignKey)` is still pointing to `auth.User` model not `Freelance` or `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`

Comment: settings.py updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its already clear from the error that there is no `auth.User` and you are pointing `author` to it. Change that.

Either use `Freelance` or `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`

```
from login.models import Freelancer

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```